# How to alter the url of a directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to change the url of a directory so that:

```
www.example.com/foo/
```

becomes

```
www.example.com
```

I can't move the files.

Putting a htaccess file using mod_rewrite to simply rewrite www.example.com to www.example.com/foo wasn't a problem

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^foo/ foo%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

However I *must* ensure that if the user requests www.example.com/foo that the http status is 404 or the user is redirected to www.example.com. Unfortunately whatever I do, it seems to end up in an infinite loop. For example this results in an infinite redirection loop:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^foo/ foo%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/foo
RewriteRule  ^foo(.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to condition on the original request sent to the server, since the `%{REQUEST_URI}` will change during the `mod_rewrite` processing, which causes the internal redirect loop.

Consequently, something like this should take care of things (for the 404, your 301 `RewriteRule` should work fine as well if you want to swap that in):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s/foo [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```